# From Manila to Canada via France and Italy

Tags: schengen, canada, filipino-citizens

I intend to apply for a tourist visa to Canada and a tourist Schengen visa. My itinerary will be from Manila to Paris, France to Rome, Italy then Canada where I plan to visit/stay for 2-3 months with an invitation letter from my daughter who is a permanent card holder. I understand I have to buy a return  ticket from Canada to Manila where I reside. Is this a feasible itinerary?  Will this affect my chance of getting a Schengen or even a visa to Canada as this is my first time to apply for a tourist visa to these countries although I have been to several countries in Asia like Japan, Korea, Hongkong, Macau, Singapore, Thailand, Malaysia, Indonesia, Vietnam, Cambodia to name a few. Will the consul in the France Embassy here in Manila look for a return flight from a member country to Manila?

Comment: I would think they will accept your round the world ticket same as a simple roundtrip ticket as proof of departure from the Schengen area, but they might want to see the Canada visa issued first since it seems to represent the majority of your travel time.

Comment: It's a great itinerary as long as it is fleshed out with the accommodation arrangements. I hope your bank statements are free from irregularities.  Your peripatetic experience makes getting a schengen a lot easier. I can't see any problems, but if you have a very specific question at the application stage, this is the right place to ask.

Comment: Thanks Tom and Gayot Tom suggested I get a Canada visa first but the approval time takes longer bec. tourists are required to take medical tests (not sure of this though) than the approval  for a Schengen visa. My question is: w

Comment: What is the usual validity date for a tourist visa to Canada?  What about the Schengen visa? I worry that my Canada visa will expire before I get a Schengen visa.  Please,I need clarification regarding this matter.

Comment: A typical Canada tourist visa has a validity period of up to 10 years, and allows multiple entries for up to six months each entry. Schengen visas generally have a much shorter validity period. If it is your first Schengen visa, it might be issued for exactly the dates on your proposed itinerary. Your Canada visa is quite unlikely to expire before you get your Schengen visa.

Answer (score 3):

In general, you should always apply for visas in *reverse* order of your itinerary. That is, apply first for the visa of the last country you visit or transit, and apply last for the visa of the first country you visit or transit.

This is because countries in the middle of your itinerary will want to know that you can lawfully enter the next country on your itinerary. This is of particular importance for Schengen visas; if you can't demonstrate that you can lawfully enter the next country on your itinerary, and that you have the money to do so, your visa may be refused.

So, you should apply for your visa to Canada first, and after you receive it, apply for your Schengen visa.

P.S.: If your daughter is a *citizen* or *permanent resident* of Canada, you may be eligible to apply for the [parent and grandparent super visa](http://www.cic.gc.ca/english/visit/supervisa.asp), which is good for up to 10 years and for multiple entries of up to *two years* each entry. This may require a little more work to procure, but if you plan to visit your daughter frequently, or make an extended visit, it may be worth looking into.

Comment: thanks,  Michael The clarity of your answer to my query is of great help